# Were bitcoins automatically converted to Bitcoin Cash?

Tags: blockchain-fork, bitcoin-cash

Don't understand about Bitcoin Cash. It is written [here](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/tags/bitcoin-cash/info):

> Bitcoin Cash is an altcoin which forked from Bitcoin in order to raise
>   the maximum block size from 1 MB to 8 MB.

But:

> Anyone who held Bitcoin prior to the fork had the same amount of
>   Bitcoin Cash following the fork.

So, bitcoins were automatically converted to Bitcoin Cash.

But they have different price and actually different currencies.

Some people want to keep Bitcons, some Bitcons Cash.

Or I understand it wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

BCH is basically a copy of the blockchain up until the point of the fork so all BTC on the bitcoin blockchain have an exact copy of BCH on the BCH blockchain. That means if you held BTC at the time of the fork, you get an equal amount of BCH *as well* - you have both. Yes, they are different currencies with different prices, and you can buy and sell them completely separately from each other